# git clone with different file permissions

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, sparse-checkout

On our server are three (in reality: thousands of) text files stored in a bare git repository: A.txt, B.txt, C.txt.

- User "admin" should view/edit them all.
- User "Foo" should view/edit "A.txt" and "B.txt" but he is not allowed to see the content of "C.txt".
- User "guest" should only be allowed to view/edit "A.txt".

All three users should be able to clone the git repository with the files they
are allowed to edit.

Is there any possibility to make this with git (...or mercurial)?

Idea: Can I make two clones of the bare git repository with the sparse checkout 
feature of git for the user "Foo" and "guest" wich include only the files they
are allowed to see?

Any other (faster) idea?

Comment: And I guess they can't just all be separate repositories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should:

- have three branches

  - guest (with only `A.txt` files)
  - users (with A and B.txt files)
  - admin (with all files)

That means frequent merges to update the different branches and propagate the different modification.

Plus, with [**gitolite**](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), you can control who can pull/push what (at a branch level), which means:

- a guest will only be able to pull the `guest` branch.
- a foo user will only be able to pull the `guest` branch and the `users` branch, while being able to push the `users` branch (or both branches if you want a user to update the content of `guest` branch).
- an admin can pull/pull all branches.